# Asp.net restful web service, operation on more than one resource in the same transaction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, restful-architecture

My understanding of  Asp.net restful web service is that for each resource , there are corresponding get,post,delete,put verbs.

But what if I have to submit a request to server that needs to operate on more than one resource?
e.g., for a submit form, I have to ask the server to create an `order` and in the same request a new `order history`.
For me , I define an `order` and `an order history` as two different resources.
And if we follow the ASP.NET MVC Web api restful web service,  we will create two controllers, one named OrderController, and the other one OrderHistoryController.
And each controller has the “get,post,delete,put” verbs.

The question is how can we make sure that the creation of an order and the creation of an order history are in one transaction ?
How and when to call the OrderHistoryController’s post method to create an OrderHistory after the Order’s creation ?

I currently am not sure how to achieve this with OrderHistory being a resource.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, you *probably* won't want PUT and DELETE operations in `OrderHistories`.  Being able to change/delete history generally isn't a good idea.  (You probably don't even want a POST operation on that resource.  The server-side logic should create its own `OrderHistory` objects any time an `Order` is created/modified/deleted.)

Aside from that...

You don't maintain a transaction (or, more generally, a unit of work) across multiple HTTP requests.  Each request would be an isolated and otherwise atomic unit of work in and of itself.

So essentially what you're looking to do here is issue a POST to the `Orders` resource to create an `Order` object.  The server-side logic in this operation would, within that same unit of work, also create any necessary corresponding records in `OrderHistories`.

Depending on how you select from these resources, you'd return information from that POST operation needed to query them.  For example, it's unlikely that you'd ever want to query an `OrderHistory` by its own identifier right away, you'd probably query by the `Order` ID.  So when creating an `Order` object, the returned server-generated ID for that object could be used by the client to query the `OrderHistories` if they want.

---

Ultimately, it sounds like the confusion here is from the mistaken notion that a RESTful service is basically a pass-through set of operations to database tables.  It isn't.  The consuming client shouldn't be responsible for maintaining transactional integrity or relational integrity.  The server-side operations maintain that.

Comment: it sounds like the confusion here is from the mistaken notion that a RESTful service is basically a pass-through set of operations to database tables. It isn't. This is exactly where my confusion is. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ike: The first rule of APIs is to *never* expose your database structure directly in the API.  You want those two things to be able to change independently of one another.  Adding/removing/changing a column/table shouldn't be a breaking change to the public API.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.